# date picker with text as default values until user changes date

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker

Is there any way to achieve below using android DatePicker api.
To have custom text e.g.. **SELECT** at the place of date, month and year by default ?

[image: Customised date picker with default text]

Comment: Is this Android Default `DatePicker` or from some library? The document should be explaining this, since it's a basic use case.

Comment: @SaranSankaran this is android NumberPicker.